# How to get the recors with count zero if there are no records

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables like [image]
I want to display the leave types with the count. For that I have written  a query like

```
SELECT VM.vacation_id,
       VM.vacation_desc,
       isnull(sum(VR.total_hours_applied),0) AS totalCount
FROM EMPTYPE_VACATIONCONFIG VC
LEFT JOIN HR_Vacation_Master VM ON VC.VACATIONID=VM.vacation_id
INNER JOIN HR_Employee_Vacation_Request VR ON VR.vacation_id=VM.vacation_id
WHERE VR.employee_id=156
  AND VC.BRANCHID=20
GROUP BY VM.vacation_desc,
         VM.vacation_id
```

my query is working fine and giving results of existed vacationids only.  like [image]
I want third leave alos with zero total.
If the employee not applied any leave(in second table), that record not coming in list. I want that record also with the totalCount zero.
How can I do it

Comment: How about replacing the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`? Did it work?

Comment: No.. Still giving existed records only.. :(

Comment: Oh wait, my bad. Just realised you are joining on the `vacation_id`.

Comment: Did you try with `case` statement??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `VR.employee_id=156` you are not allowing null row.

You can do that :

```
SELECT VM.vacation_id,
       VM.vacation_desc,
       isnull(sum(VR.total_hours_applied),0) AS totalCount
FROM EMPTYPE_VACATIONCONFIG VC
LEFT JOIN HR_Vacation_Master VM ON VC.VACATIONID=VM.vacation_id
LEFT JOIN HR_Employee_Vacation_Request VR 
    ON VR.vacation_id=VM.vacation_id AND VR.employee_id=156
WHERE VC.BRANCHID=20
GROUP BY VM.vacation_desc,
         VM.vacation_id
```

Leave me a comment if this not works, I have some other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If one employee didn't apply any leave, there shouldn't have a record with his(or her) employee id in table HR_Employee_Vacation_Request , right? So I think you should use HR_Vacation_Master left outer join table HR_Employee_Vacation_Request .